# Deleted .pch file by mistake

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, precompiled-headers

I have deleted my .pch file by mistake, and now my project cannot be built anymore.

What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567051/xcode-deleted-pch-file-by-mistake-can-it-be-recovered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you don't have version control?

You could just use the contents of a pch file from a different project or create a new one. If you search in your build settings for "pch" you'll see what the name of this pch file is expected to be and where it should be in your project